# Pandas any() returning false with true values present

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a largely empty dataframe of poorly formatted dates that I converted into DateTime format.

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""issue_date,issue_date_dt
,
,
19600215.0,1960-02-15
,
,""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=[1])
```

Which produces

```
    issue_date  issue_date_dt
0   NaN         NaT
1   NaN         NaT
2   19600215.0  1960-02-15
3   NaN         NaT
4   NaN         NaT
```

I'd expect that I could use df.any() to find whether there was a value in a row or column. `axis=0` behaves as expected:

```
df.any(axis=0)

issue_date       True
issue_date_dt    True
dtype: bool
```

But `axis=1` just returns false for all rows all the time.

```
df.any(axis=1)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255267/column-arithmetic-in-pandas-dataframe-using-dates) (not a dupe). For some reason, `np.isnan()` is not applicable to `datetime64[ns]` columns. This may have caused the inconsistency.

Comment: You could try `df.fillna(0).any(axis=1)`

Comment: may be `df.dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23070

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure *why* this is occuring<sup>[1]</sup>, my best guess is that the differing datatypes along the first axis cause this unexpected result, as `any` works as expected along axis `0`.  *However*, I would argue that the workaround to this is actually a better approach anyways, as it is more immediately clear to a reader what exactly you are checking for.

---

This could potentially be a bug, if you agree I would recommend opening an issue on the `pandas` [github page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

The workaround is straightforward, make use of `notnull` to use `any` on a homogenous mask of type `bool`, rather than a DataFrame containing mixed types

```
df.notnull().any(1)
```

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> This appears to have been [recognized as a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23070)</sub>